# How do I build a home-made apparatus for identifying what minerals are present in water?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water, home-experiment

While there are many readily available kits in the commercial market for testing the type of minerals present in water,

- is there a way we can build one at home?

I am ready to spend some bucks on raw materials, if I can get the knowledge of how to build such apparatus

Answer (score 1):

*This probably not what you are looking for, but the cheapest and least time-consuming analysis is the one done by others for free.*

Over here (Germany), local water suppliers are required by law ([Trinkwasserverordnung - TrinkwV](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/trinkwv_2001/BJNR095910001.html)) to monitor the quality of potable water. This includes a large number of microbiological and chemical parameters. The details are given in the annexes 1-5 of the TrinkwV.

The results are published and are are available online at no cost.

Examples (mostly in German) are:

- [RheinEnergie](https://www.rheinenergie.com/de/privatkundenportal/energie_wasser/wasser_2/qualitaet__haerte/qualitaet__haerte_1.php) (Cologne area)
- [RWW - Rheinisch-Westfälische Wasserwerksgesellschaft](http://www.rww.de/trinkwasser/wasserqualitaet/trinkwasseranalysen/) (one of the largest suppliers in Germany)